# Can I eliminate duplicate code for below derived classes and move to abstract base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a abstract base class, starting a `timer` which is common to all derived class,

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Start() { _timer.Start(); }
}
```

Now I need to load different JSON configuration files for each derived class and create the file,

```
public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    private readonly List<config> configs = new List<config>();

    public DerivedClass1()
    {
        configs = JsonSettings.GetConfigurations(@"./Configurations/1.json");
    }
    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        foreach (var configuration in configs)
        {
            JsonSettings.CreateConfigFile(configuration);
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    private readonly List<config> configs = new List<config>();

    public DerivedClass2()
    {
        configs = JsonSettings.GetConfigurations(@"./Configurations/2.json");
    }
    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        foreach (var configuration in configs)
        {
            JsonSettings.CreateConfigFile(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

As I see there are lots of codes are duplicated in various derived class.

Can I move these piece of code as well as `abstract base` class or is there another way?

Comment: What does your `BaseClass` and derived classes represent? What are their function?

Comment: The best practice would be having a separate utility class implementation, which will have these duplicate code. And inject that class into your new classes via dependency injection. 

"Favor Composition over Inheritance"

Comment: I'm not putting full code, but what is missing?

Comment: @Naruto, could you please give some example?

Comment: sure! give me a minute!

Comment: added some sample code. let me know if it won't fit ur requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could simplify your code to this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual List<config> configs { get; set; } = new List<config>();
    public virtual void Start()
    {
        _timer.Start();
        foreach (var configuration in configs)
        {
            JsonSettings.CreateConfigFile(configuration);
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass1()
    {
        configs = JsonSettings.GetConfigurations(@"./Configurations/1.json");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass2()
    {
        configs = JsonSettings.GetConfigurations(@"./Configurations/2.json");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface BaseClass
{
    void Start();
}

public interface IBaseClassUtil
{
    void Start();
    void setConfigs(List<config> configs);
}

public class BaseClassUtil : IBaseClassUtil
{
    System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    public  List<config> _configs { get; set; } = new List<config>();
    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Start();
        foreach (var configuration in _configs)
        {
            JsonSettings.CreateConfigFile(configuration);
        }
    }

    public void setConfigs(List<config> configs)
    {
        _configs = configs;
    }
}
public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    private IBaseClassUtil _baseUtility;
    public DerivedClass1(IBaseClassUtil baseUtility)
    {
        _baseUtility = baseUtility;
        _baseUtility.setConfigs( JsonSettings.GetConfigurations(@"./Configurations/1.json"));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _baseUtility.Start();
    }
}

public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    private IBaseClassUtil _baseUtility;
    public DerivedClass2(IBaseClassUtil baseUtility)
    {
        _baseUtility = baseUtility;
        _baseUtility.setConfigs(JsonSettings.GetConfigurations(@"./Configurations/2.json"));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _baseUtility.Start();
    }
}
```

This might be oveer engineered. Or might not suit ur current requirement. 
Advantages would be

1. In future if you want u want to have different implementation for IBaseClassUtil  it will be easier

   2. And huge advantage would be this code is testable

Answer (score 1):

If the classes differ by nothing but the configuration path, then you can have only one derived class that takes the path as a parameter in its ctor.

```
public DerivedClass(string configurationPath)
{
    configs = JsonSettings.GetConfigurations(configurationPath);
}
```

Put please note that a decision on including inheritance in your architecture is *not* about code duplication, and by not giving us any information on the functions or even names of the classes (`BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` mean nothing. What do they represent? What's their function? Why are they related?) you give us no way of really helping you with your design.